# Unable to resize image and keep image quality

Tags: images, resizing, irfanview

I have a image that i want to use as a header on my site but i have problem resizing the image. The header size is 960x290 but the image size is 1600x1200. I used IrfanView and resized the width of the image from 1600 to 960 but i have problem with the height. When i select 960 for width the program auto picks the height value to 720 to keep the aspect ratio and the image look normal with the new size 960x290. But if i uncheck "preserve the aspect ratio" and enter for height 280 the resized image become messed up (stretched). Is there any way to change the height value to 290 and keep the "normal look" of the image or this is not possible?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to crop it, if you change proportions it will get distorted.
Try [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), its very good for this kind of stuff and it's free.
[Docs](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tutorial-quickie-crop.html) will help you get it done.

Comment: So, without cropping it is not possible to get the size i want without distorting the image? Because cropping this image in particular is not a solution for me.

Comment: If you change the apect ratio it will get distorted so yes, cropping is your only option.

Comment: Maybe you can edit the image so you use original elementa from it, and fill the empty space to match your site design. Show me your site and image and I can give you some advice.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i just wanted to know if something like this is possible or not.

Comment: Also Paint .NET is a good solution.

Comment: Look, basically you want a square to fit in a wide rectangle; either you squeeze it in that you flatten it and loose aspect ratio, or you crop it (cut top and/or bottom), that's all your choices! You cannot reduce the height and keep the same width, and expect that the aspect ratio (height/width) will remain the same.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want distortion, you need to maintain the aspect ratio.  If you don't want to crop, your other option would be to resize based on the height, which will preserve everything but give you a narrower image.  Then put the image on a 960 x 290 (or 280?) background, positioned where it works the best for you.

Pick a fill for the background that works with the image.  Some options would be:

- a complementary color that highlights the image
- neutral, like black or grey, to fill the space
- match a color to something in the image with a color picker (you can also blend colors from an area so the background blends with the edges of the image)
- use a simple pattern or texture for the background
- use a "material" for the background, like an image of wood, cloth, marble, grass, sky, etc., whatever works with the content of the image.
- pick a background area of the image and replicate it as filler, potentially including things like enlarging it or making it partially transparent.

Answer (score 3):

**You really have 2 choices here and maybe four...**

1. The image needs to be cropped either on the top, bottom, or both to accommodate the 290px header height
2. The header on your site needs to allow for 720px tall images

---

**Maybe a third...**

3. Use the image as a background which dips behind the content of your site

[image]

---

**Maybe a fourth...**

4. Add more content to the left and right sides of your current header image so that the dimensions are 3972x1200

   - 3972x1200 is the same aspect ratio as 960x290 so scaling your large image down to the size you need will be easy and proportionate